# why do I keep getting "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" when calling 'screen' in pygame?

Tags: python, module, pygame, typeerror

I'm not sure if screen is the problem, but every time I run this code:

```
import pygame  
import engine
import sys

# screen config
height = 500
width = 500
dimension = 8 #dimension of an 8x8 chess board
square_size = height//dimension
FPS = 30

#pygame settings 
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tapton Chess Club')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen.fill(pygame.Color("white"))
board_format = engine.game_logic()

def draw_board(screen, board_format):
    draw_squares(screen)

#draw squares on screen using 2d array
def draw_squares(screen):
        square_colours = [pygame.Color("#e8ebef"), pygame.Color("#7d8796")]
        for row in range(dimension):
                for column in range(dimension):
                        sq_colour = square_colours[((row+column)%2)] #used to find the colour of the square
                        pygame.draw.rect(screen, sq_colour, pygame.rect(row*square_size, column*square_size, square_size, square_size))

#pygame event loop to register user input
running = True 
while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                        exit()
        draw_board(screen, board_format)
        clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

I get these errors:
[picture of output in IDLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPaBT.png)

Please help me, I'm very new to this and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I recently rearranged a lot of my files, but that is the only answer I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use

```
pygame.rect(row*square_size, column*square_size, square_size, square_size)
```

instead of

```
pygame.Rect(row*square_size, column*square_size, square_size, square_size)
```

`pygame.rect` is a module, `pygame.Rect` is a class.